# REGEX Match all and replace the String with Other strings

Tags: php, regex, search, preg-replace

I am using REGEX to match all the patterns and replace each match value with an other string.

I have these type of codes in my content

```
[amazon template=AmazonPreisNormal&amp;asin=B00EJKWCJ4]
[amazon template=amazon_nur_eur&amp;asin=B00EJKWCJ4]
```

What i want to do is replace the template= value with another string as described below

for **AmazonPreisNormal** i want to replace it with **widget-pricenormal** and so for all the others

after the preg_match_all i got this array as follows:

```
Array
 (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => template=AmazonPreisNormal&
        [1] => template=amazon_nur_eur&
        [2] => template=AmazonLink&
        [3] => template=preisbeiamazon12&
        [4] => template=preis10&
        [5] => template=beiamazon11&
        [6] => template=beiamazon&
        [7] => template=xx_bei_amazon&
        [8] => template=beiamazon11br&
        [9] => template=beiamazon12&
        [10] => template=Image&
        [11] => template=preisbeiamazon12&
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => AmazonPreisNormal
        [1] => amazon_nur_eur
        [2] => AmazonLink
        [3] => preisbeiamazon12
        [4] => preis10
        [5] => beiamazon11
        [6] => beiamazon
        [7] => xx_bei_amazon
        [8] => beiamazon11br
        [9] => beiamazon12
        [10] => Image
        [11] => preisbeiamazon12
    )

  )
```

Now what i want is to get each of the matching template value and replace it with another value like
for **AmazonPreisNormal** i want to replace it with **widget-pricenormal** ad so on for all the other values with different string.

i am trying something like this but never getting the output

```
    $numberOfMatches = count($matches[0]);

    for ($i = 0 $i < $numberOfMatches; $i++;) { 
       $templaname =  $matches[0][$i];
    }

    if($templaname = 'beiamazon11') {
      $replacementTemplate = 'template="widget-beiamazon11"';
    }elseif($templaname = 'AmazonPreisNormal')  {
      $replacementTemplate = 'template="widget-pricenormal"';
    }elseif($templaname = 'amazon_nur_eur')  {
       $replacementTemplate = 'template="widget-nureur"';
    }elseif($templaname = 'AmazonLink')  {
       $replacementTemplate = 'template="widget-amazonlink"';
    }elseif($templaname = 'preisbeiamazon12')  {
       $replacementTemplate = 'template="widget-preisebeiamazon12"';
    }elseif($templaname = 'preis10')  {
       $replacementTemplate = 'template="widget-preis10"';
    }
```

Any Help regarding this will be apperciated

Comment: Could you please add your final output what you want based on input array? it will helps us to understand what actually you are trying to do and where is the issue?

Comment: Updated the Question please check

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback` to check what you matched and replace accordingly.

Comment: any demo example you have for that?